# Ignore pushing directory, but still track in Git

Tags: git, tracking

Is there any way to ignore a directory when you push remotely? The catch is I don't want to ignore it. I still want to track the directory, and have local commits and branches for it. Say, I'm working on a project that relies on a database. This project does not have transitional schema or anything. It is populated with data for testing. I have a symbolic link for MySQL's folder/files (MyISAM MYD/MYI) to my local repository. I want the database and the commits in sync, but cannot push the database (or assets, etc). I tried a submodule, with no avail - the parent repo ignores the child submodule changes. How would I go about this? Example structure:

/repo/my-project <-- git repo
/repo/my-project/src <-- push commits related to this section to a remote repo that uses this as the root directory

/repo/my-project/mysql <-- track these but don't push them
/repo/my-project/mysql/db_1/table_1.frm
/repo/my-project/mysql/db_1/table_1.MYD
/repo/my-project/mysql/db_1/table_1.MYI

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push a given branch, you push the commits on that branch. If those commits include the contents of a given directory, you will be pushing that content.

Your two options are:

- Keep that directory on a branch (or branches) which are never merged into the branches you push. You can still merge other changes into that branch freely, of course.
- Keep that directory in a separate repository. The easiest approach would then be to symlink that directory to the real location of the repository, and ignore the path. (You can ignore it in `.git/info/excludes` to avoid even publishing that gitignore entry.) More detailed instructions:

  ```
  cd path/to/project

  # move the directory outside your project
  mv database-dir ..

  # add an ignored symlink to it
  echo "database-dir" >> .git/info/excludes
  ln -s ../database-dir database-dir

  # create a new repo in the directory to track it
  cd ../database-dir
  git init; git add .; git commit
  ```

Comment: The first option makes sense. I just need to be very careful, as I like to abuse `git add -A`. The second option I don't understand. I found if there is a .git in the real repo (sub-directory), then it causes the parent .git to ignore that section.. or act strange. If would be good if the .git were one level up from the real repo, but I don't have that control without a bunch of links. I'll try though. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: I edited in a quick outline of what I had in mind on the second option.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but the structure above was an example. In the case of option #2, I would have no reason to put the database dir (or symbolic link) inside the project dir. So you're saying track them separately, which seems tedious and the same as the answer below. I'll go with option #1. Per-branch ignores would be interesting.. (like per-user or per-project). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to ignore files from inclusion to your repository by adding them to the .gitignore file -- but I don't think that's what you want.

Try this: http://book.git-scm.com/4_ignoring_files.html

Comment: "The catch is I don't want to ignore it." You're right, it's not what the OP wants. Not much point posting the answer if you already know that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not track the database in a separate repository without a remote branch?

(Note that if you never push remotely, you wont have a backup if your hard drive fails.)

Comment: I want to checkout matching revisions of the DB and codebase easily. Also, have to work around not messing up the existing project hierarchy.